# Rename first two character based on condition in python

Tags: python

Folder contains images in format `jpg`, and `png`.

Here we need to achieve:

Image files name start with 11BHBHHJJKKKKK.JPG, 11BCBHHJJKKKKK.JPG, 11BKBHHJJKKKKK.JPG, 33GFHJJKKKKJK.JPG, 33JHNNHHJJJJJ.JPG, 44HJFHJFHJFHF.PNG, 44HJFHJFKKHF.JPG

So here we need to change image name using following conditions:
image name start with "11" change to "AA", "11BHBHHJJKKKKK.JPG" to "AABHBHHJJKKKKK.JPG"
image name start with "33" change to "BB", "33GFHJJKKKKJK.JPG" to "BBJHNNHHJJJJJ.JPG"
image name start with "44" change to "CC", "44HJFHJFKKHF.JPG" to "CCHJFHJFKKHF.JPG"

Any suggestion please.

I have tried

```
from PIL import Image
import glob
import os
import re

image_list = []
imagepath = 'C/dataimg/*.jpg'
for filename in glob.glob(imagepath): #assuming gif
    head, tail = os.path.split(filename)
    print(tail)
    print(str(tail)[:2])
    newimage=tail.replace("11", "AA")
    newimage.save(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like below, where you check every single condition you're looking for.

```
from pathlib import Path
for filename in glob.glob(imagepath): #assuming gif
    path = Path(filename)
    head = os.path.split(filename)[1]
    if head.startswith('11'):
        os.rename(filename, os.path.join(path.parent, head.replace('11', 'AA')))
    elif head.startswith('33'):
        os.rename(filename, os.path.join(path.parent, head.replace('33', 'BB')))
    elif head.startswith('44'):
        os.rename(filename, os.path.join(path.parent, head.replace('44', 'CC')))
```

Comment: Rename of images working but not saving  image in folder i have tried cv2.imwrite(head,dst) and head.save  . After head.replace we need to save image in folder .Any suggestion?

Comment: I've edited it to rename the file as well, hope it works as intended.